# How to modify 3d vehicle color based on the Png image in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-container

There is a vehicle in unity game project. Need to create the mod system for that vehicle skin based on the png image. we are not sure how to proceed with this but we are sure definitely there is a way to do this because have seen some games are working with mod system. Did anyone have any idea?

Comment: Well you have to have uvs on your mesh of the vehicle. I am not an expert on this, but if the png is a texture, you should set it as the mesh’s texture, and edit the uvs. I am not sure, though. I have not done this before.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Textures](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Textures.html) are applied to objects using [materials](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Materials.html).
To change the color, I would assign the new material in the inspector, or try to set the color of the material in the material [properties](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MaterialsAccessingViaScript.html).
Either can be done with code if that needs to be done in runtime.